# How can i add a texture to billboard particles?

Tags: texturing, uv, blender-internal-render-engine, particles

I'm using a billboard-type particle in order to show a texture/plane look at the camera, the problem is i have the billboard option selected so i can't choose 'object' and the planes from the billboard are working great, but how can i add an object or a (single) texture in order to replace the gray plane the billboard offers?

Comment: Cycles or Blender Internal?

Comment: billboards use the material chosen at the top of the particles render settings. This works in BI but cycles does not appear to render billboard particles. I just reported it as [a bug](https://developer.blender.org/T48467)

Comment: I'm using Blender Internal; Blender-Render.

Comment: @sambler Where's that option? How do i set it? I can't find it or i just got confused.

Comment: The material choice for particles? In the [particles Render panel](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YiLGW.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

As answered in the [bug report by Brecht](https://developer.blender.org/T48467), billboards is a feature that is not supported by cycles and isn't planned to be added any time soon.

To get billboards working you need to be using the blender internal render engine. By default the material used for particles is the same material used on the object emitting the particles, you can change the material used for the billboards in the particle settings in the render panel.

[image: particle render settings]